# Change the order of a table according to preferences given in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table A as below

```
Name   Food    PreferenceOrder
------------------------------
Jon    Burger  1
Jon    Coke    2
Jon    Pizza   3
Jon    Fries   4
Sam    Pizza   1
Sam    Coke    2
```

I have another table B that can override the preference order above

```
Name   Food    PreferredOverFood
--------------------------------
Jon    Pizza   Fries
Jon    Coke    Burger
Jon    Fries   Coke
Sam    Coke    Pizza
```

Basically here, Food should come before PreferredOverFood (Pizza > Fries)

Now, I want to reorder table A according to Table B preferences, so the result should be like

```
Name   Food    PreferenceOrder
------------------------------
Jon    Burger  4
Jon    Pizza   1
Jon    Fries   3
Jon    Coke    2
Sam    Pizza   2
Sam    Coke    1
```

I tried by using cursors, so I created a dynamic cursor, with each fetch I am updating Table B with table A preference, but since we are updating things row by row its not considering rows that violate the previous preferences, so I am getting Fries before Pizza (since Fries > Coke is run and it forgot about first preference (Pizza > Fries)).

So dynamic cursor is not working, (its not refreshing the result set after update). Can I use CTE or something to do like above. (Can also have circular dependencies, but not too worried about it for now)

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using?  There are different methods depending...

Comment: Im using MS SQL server

Comment: What if table B has cycles?

Comment: It would be better if we can handle it, if not its fine.

Comment: Well, how would circular references be handled?

Comment: If there are circular references, I want to error out